# Getting Access to Products No Longer Available From Microsoft

Tags: legacy

As a consequence of a legal settlement with Sun regarding the Java technology, Microsoft has removed certain products from being available directly from them through any means. Here is an excerpt from their MSDN site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/aa948864.aspx

> **Products Unavailable due to
>   Java-related Settlement**
>
> Some products have been removed from
>   Subscriber Downloads due to the terms
>   of Java-related settlements Microsoft
>   made with Sun Microsystems. These
>   products are no longer available from
>   Microsoft in any form, but may be
>   available through third-party
>   resellers or Web sites.

This list includes large variety of products, including Office 200, Windows 98, Windows XP, Visual Studio 6.0, VSS 6.0d, and many more.

Microsoft suggests you can get these products from various "resellers" - but won't go further than that.

**Does anyone know where developers can obtain access to these products (in our case for testing purposes) from inexpensive, reputable resellers? Or better yet, a legal and free resource to get access to the original media if you have an existing, legal license key?**

Comment: Have you tried eBay or amazon?

Comment: They are certainly an option, but it would be preferable not to have to pay for the product again if you simply lost the original install media, but still have your license key.

Comment: Can someone please make a user named "Microsoft Effigy" just so we can repeatedly downvote it over and over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the link for the page from which you pulled that excerpt?

I didn't do an exhaustive search, but Windows XP and VSS 6.0d are both available on my MSDN subsciber downloads page.

However, I don't see Windows 98 or Office 2000 listed.

Comment: The link is not hard to find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa948864.aspx